# JSpeex vs porting Speex in android?

Tags: android, audio, speex, jspeex

I'd like to use the speex library to handle echo cancellation on an android phone and I found a link to the jspeex project in the speex website.
As it is already ported to java, I think that it could spare me some dev time but I'm still wondering which solution would be the best in terms of working efficiency

- Using jspeex in android
- Using speex through JNI

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: When I said working efficiency, I meant which one would be the fastest to do the echo cancellation process.